# Should I use std::seed_seq to seed std::mt19937?

Tags: c++, random

Is it ok that 624 integers generated by random_device are directly used to seed mt19937?
Should I use seed_seq?

```cpp
class RDSeq {
public:
    template <typename It>
    void generate (It first, It last) const {
        std::random_device rd {};
        std::generate(first, last, std::ref(rd));
    }
};

std::mt19937 random {};
RDSeq seq {};
random.seed(seq);
```

Comment: Should you seed mt19937 at all?

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes.  For statistical reasons, the random engine needs to be seeded well.

Comment: By filling the full 19937-bit state, and not just the first 32-bits. http://www.pcg-random.org/posts/cpp-seeding-surprises.html

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is that you don't need to, all Mersenne Twister constructors call `seed_seq` on whatever state you give it regardless of its size.

---

This is code I've written to fill the initial state of a Mersenne Twister.

```cpp
template <typename T = std::uint32_t, typename Enable = void>
class Mersenne;

template <typename T>
using AllowForUnsigned = std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned_v<T>>;

template <typename T>
class Mersenne<T, AllowForUnsigned<T>>
{
public:
    Mersenne();
    T operator()();

    using result_type = T;
    static constexpr result_type min();
    static constexpr result_type max();

private:
    using Twister = std::conditional_t<sizeof(T) <= 4, std::mt19937, std::mt19937_64>;
    Twister engine_;
};

// Mersenne class implementation
template <typename T>
Mersenne<T, AllowForUnsigned<T>>::Mersenne()
{
    // Proper seeding of mt19937 taken from:
    // https://kristerw.blogspot.com/2017/05/seeding-stdmt19937-random-number-engine.html
    // Body walkthrough at end of file
    std::random_device rd;
    std::array<T, Twister::state_size> seed_data;
    std::generate_n(std::begin(seed_data), seed_data.size(), std::ref(rd));
    std::seed_seq seq(std::begin(seed_data), std::end(seed_data));
    engine_ = Twister(seq);
}
```

Here is a [clickable link](https://kristerw.blogspot.com/2017/05/seeding-stdmt19937-random-number-engine.html) to the blog post that I adapted into a class for seeding a Mersenne Twister. The meat of the class is in the default constructor which I included above. The idea is exactly like you said, to fill the entire 19937-bit state with seed data.

The full implementation is [here](https://gitlab.com/sweenish/seeded_prng). Most of the other stuff is there to provide compatibility with the distributions in `<random>`. There are a lot of comments aimed at a classroom setting. It is worth mentioning that unless `random_device` has access to true entropy, it will use a deterministic method of creating seed values. `seed_seq` is also deterministic, but it can be alleviated to an extent if `random_device` at least has an entropic source. **NOTE**: `seed_seq` is also called on Mersenne Twister constructors, so even if you provide just 32-bits of state, a full state will be generated, but it's less than ideal: [link](http://www.pcg-random.org/posts/cpp-seeding-surprises.html)

The short story is that providing just 32-bits of initial state will cause the PRNG to simply never generate certain values, ever. People may argue that it's sufficient for playground purposes, or that it matters less if you're always filtering it through a distribution, and I think that's a fair point. But at the same time, a PRNG that will never select certain values is just as bad as `rand()`.

Others will also make the case that once you start caring about this, the C++ Standard Library (people here go nuts if you say STL, and while they're technically correct, I've never had a good-faith technical discussion go off the rails) `<random>` simply may not be good enough for you anyway. They are not cryptographically secure PRNGs, and are easy to mis-use, like being allowed to use 32-bits for a PRNG that has a 19937-bit state size.

EDIT: My constructor builds a `seed_seq`; I'm just attempting to guarantee that a specific constructor gets invoked.

Comment: No matter how you seed mt19937, even if you don't provide a seed, the generator will go through its full cycle of length $$2^{19937} - 1$$. In particular it will generate all $$2^{32}$$ unsigned integers.

Comment: mt19937 has one cycle. The seed determines where in that cycle you start. The quality of the generator is independent of the starting position. The original MT always started in approximately the same area of the cycle, which was bad. The implementation specified in the C++ Standard does not suffer from that problem.

Comment: And yet, the page I'm citing claims otherwise. That a poor seed will indeed result in a poor PRNG that will never land on certain values.